# Convert the number of observations in a dataset into a macro variable

Tags: sas

I am trying to determine the number of observations in a dataset, then convert this number into a macro variable that i can use as part of a loop. I've searched the web for answers and not had much luck. I would post some example code I've tried but I have literally no idea how to approach this.

Could anybody assist?

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 3):

SAS stores dataset information, such as number of observations, separately, so the key is to access this information without having to read in the entire dataset.
The following code will do just that, the if 0 part is never true so the dataset isn't read, however the information is.

```
data _null_;
if 0 then set sashelp.class nobs=n;
call symput('numobs',n);
stop;
run;

%put n=&numobs;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also get it from dictionary.tables like this:

```
proc sql noprint;
select nobs into :nobs 
from dictionary.tables 
where libname='YourLibrary' and memname='YourDatasetName';
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

Create macro variable:

```
data _null_;
    set sashelp.class;
    call symput("nbobs",_N_);
run;
```

See result:

```
%put &nbobs;
```

Use it:

```
data test;
    do i = 1 to &nbobs;
        put i;
    end;
run;
```